# What if I stored Personally identifiable information (PII) on cloud but with IP restricted environment or using VPN. Will it be GDPR compliance?

Tags: gdpr

I have a requirement to `fetch` and `search` (partial search, full text search, fuzzy search etc) `personally identifiable information (PII)` data in Admin Panel and I can restrict my environment with `IP white labeling` or using `VPN`. What if I `stored PII without encryption (as plaintext) on cloud` but with `IP restricted` environment or using `VPN`. Will it be `GDPR compliance`?

Answer (score 1):

Impossible to say from what you write here.

- The GDPR requires you to have comprehensive policies and processes in addition to technical means which safeguard PII. Arguably the technical details are the *least* relevant -- who decides which IPs get whitelisted? What are your contracts with the cloud providers?
- A colleague in IT operations repeats the quote "there is no cloud, there are just other people's computers." Various cloud providers have their servers in different locations, the big ones even allow the user to select where the data will be.

The GDPR is new enough that you cannot possibly rely on answers from random folks on the internet (including mine). You need to consult an expert.

Your company should have appointed a data security officer. If it hasn't, that's the first step.